# Making an upload file invisible over a div

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I'm trying to place an invisible upload file button over a div button, but the icon that sits in the centre of the div isn't clickable. The rest of the div is clickable, but the icon isnt. Can anyone help me make it clickable?

html:

```
<div class="phoneUpload">
    <input type="file" class="file" (change)="uploadImage($event)" />
    <ion-icon name="add" class="addIcon"></ion-icon>
    <h5 class="uploadText"> Upload </h5>
</div>
```

css:

```
phoneUpload {
flex: 1;
height: 150px;
width: 150px;
margin-left: 7%;
margin-right: 10%;
background: #F8DE7E;

.file {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.addIcon {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #9174d6;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: -65%;
}

.uploadText {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9174d6;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  margin-top: -1%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this working fine for me.

```css
.phoneUpload {
 height: 150px;
 width: 150px;
 background: #F8DE7E;
 justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
 margin:0 auto
}

.addIcon {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #9174d6;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.uploadText {
  text-align: center;
  color: #9174d6;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: "Open Sans";
}
input.uploadimghide {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class="phoneUpload">
        <input class="uploadimghide" type="file" class="file" (change)="uploadImage($event)" />
        <ion-icon name="add" class="addIcon"></ion-icon>
        <h5 class="uploadText"> Upload </h5>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```